# Custom wallpaper for Windows 2016+ on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, desktop-customization

Having setup a new Windows 2019 base image, I want to customize the background to indicate production environment - but still retain the [`bginfo`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/bginfo) style AWS stats in the top right.

There isn't much documentation for changing the EC2 default wallpaper or it refers to the Windows 2012 and older way.

How do you customise the wallpaper background for Windows 2016+ on `ec2launch`?

Answer (score 2):

The default EC2Launch wallpaper is found in

```
C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Ec2Wallpaper.jpg
```

I replaced that with my custom version, then ran these scripts to reset the wallpaper

```
Import-Module "C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Module\Ec2Launch.psd1"; 

Get-ChildItem $env:LOCALAPPDATA -filter ec2Wallpaper*.jpg | Remove-Item # Remove this users wallpaper files

Clear-Wallpaper
Set-Wallpaper
New-WallpaperSetup
```

You need to log off/log on for it to take effect.

** Not all of these PowerShell commands may be required, this is what I tried scatter gun style and it worked (running as administrator)

** Running ec2launch with sysprep to reimage will replace the custom wallpaper in `C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\`